# angularjs Master-Detail using factory & routeParams: how to write detailcontroller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

first off, I am new to stackoverflow & angularjs, so forgive me if my question is terrible.

for a simple news app I am making a master- detail view with angularjs, problem: I cant get the detail view to work, master works fine, links correct, but then I cant get the json inside the detailview. I dont see how I should set the routeParams & factory injection right inside the detail controller. here is what I have:

index.html

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="test">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>angular master-detail live-data test</title>

</head>
    <body>
        <div class="main"> 

            <div ng-view></div>

        </div> <!--/main-->

        <script src="angular/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="angular/angular-route.js"></script>

        <script src="script/app.js"></script>
        <script src="script/controllers/newsController.js"></script>
        <script src="script/services/newsFactory.js"></script>
        <script src="script/constants.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

factory

```
    (function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('test')
        .factory('newsFactory', newsFactory);


    newsFactory.$inject = ['$http', 'GLOBALS'];
    function newsFactory($http, GLOBALS) {
        var factory = {};

        factory.getItems = function () {
            return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: GLOBALS.newsUrl
            });
        };
        return factory;
    }   
})();
```

and finally the controllers

```
 // newsController.js << MASTER
(function () {
    'use strict';


    angular.module('test')
        .controller('newsController', newsController);

    newsController.$inject = ['newsFactory'];
    function newsController(newsFactory) {
        var vm = this;                                  

        newsFactory.getItems()          
            .success(function (items) {
                vm.items = items;
                })
                .error(function (err) {
                    alert('something went wrong!')
                });
    }
})();

// newsController.js << DETAIL
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('test')
        .controller('newsItemController', newsItemController);

    newsItemController.$inject = ['$routeParams', 'newsFactory'];

    function newsItemController($routeParams, newsFactory) {
        var vm = this,
            id = $routeParams.id;
        vm.item = newsFactory.getItem = function (id) {
            return items[id -1];
        }

    }
})();
```

I see the problem has to do with the routeParams  in combination with the injection of the factory, but I dont see how. thank you in forehand

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('test', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(moduleConfig);

    moduleConfig.$inject = ['$routeProvider'];

    function moduleConfig($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
         templateUrl: 'partials/home.html'
        })
        .when('/home', {
          templateUrl: 'partials/home.html'
        })
        .when('/news/:id', {
          templateUrl: 'partials/news.html'//,
        })
        .otherwise({
          redirectTo: '/'  
        })
    }
```

constants.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('test')
        .constant('GLOBALS', {
                newsUrl: 'data/news.json'
            });
})();
```

Comment: Possible issue: `newsItemController.js` is not included into the HTML.

Comment: its inside the same file newsController.js (confusing comment inside code indeed, just corrected it, thanks for noticing)

Comment: Is it possible to post what that looks like?

Comment: sure. hang on a minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `newsItemController` you are creating a new function on the `newsFactory`. This is obviously wrong, because you are also acessing `items` which is not existing in `newsItemController`.

Your factory should be the only place where you hold the `items` and where you provide methods to access them:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('test').factory('newsFactory', newsFactory);

    newsFactory.$inject = ['$http', 'GLOBALS'];

    function newsFactory($http, GLOBALS) {
        var newsItems = [];
        return {
            getItems: function () {
                return $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: GLOBALS.newsUrl
                }).success(function (items) {
                    newsItems = items;
                    return newsItems;
                }); 
            },
            getItem: function (id) {
                return newsItems[id];
            }
        };
    }   
})();
```

You would still be able to do everything the same in `newsController` but in `newsItemController` you would call:

```
vm.item = newsFactory.getItem(id);
```

**Update**: Full `NewsItemController`

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('test')
        .controller('newsItemController', newsItemController);

    newsItemController.$inject = ['$routeParams', 'newsFactory'];

    function newsItemController($routeParams, newsFactory) {
        var vm = this;
        var id = $routeParams.id;
        vm.item = newsFactory.getItem(id);
    }
})();
```

Comment: the mistake I made is clearly in the newsItemcontroller indeed, that makes sense, would it be possible to show what the newsItemController would look like in totall in a post? this would be very very helpfiull, then I can study a working basic setup.  last I ask of you, thanks!!!

Comment: I have added the controller to the answer.

Comment: thank you, it does give me 1. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =

Comment: 2.Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: newsFactoryProvider <- newsFactory

Comment: were does 1. occur? I did write it without testing since I have no running angular app here.

Comment: at newsFactory.js :            getItems = function () {

Comment: do you have any idea?

Comment: yes, I'm stupid :) => look at the solution now. it is `getItems: function () {..}` not `getItems = function () {..}`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to configure your angular module with $routeProvider service. I guess you have registered your module in the app.js which is not provided in here.

in that js file you can put something..

```
angular.module('test',[ngRoute])
.config(['$routeProvider'function($routeProvider){

           when('/main', {
                    templateUrl: 'main.html',
                    controller: 'newsController'
              }).
           when('/details', {
                    templateUrl: 'details.html',
                    controller: 'newsItemController'
              }).
otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/main'
                });

}]);
```

Comment: true, sorry, here it is, I call the controller on the partials like so: <div ng-controller="newsItemController as newsItemCtrl">  I will updated orriginal post with app.js right away